# Spring Autowiring class vs. interface?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have this Spring config:

```
<bean id="boo" class="com.x.TheClass"/>
```

The class `TheClass` implements `TheInterface`.  Then I have this (hypothetical) Java code:

```
@Autowired
TheInterface x;

@Autowired
TheClass y;
```

The autowiring of `TheInterface` works but the autowiring of `TheClass` fails.  Spring gives me a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for the class.

Why can you wire the interface and not the class?

Comment: Is there anything special about this class, like it being 'final', or having other instrumentation, like @Transactional, on it. You might be either missing an instrumentation lib, like CGLIB, or trying to create a subclass proxy on a final class.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Normally, both will work, you can autowire interfaces or classes.

There's probably an autoproxy generator somewhere in your context, which is wrapping your `boo` bean in a generated proxy object. This proxy object will implement `TheInterface`, but will not be a `TheClass`. When using autoproxies, you need to program to the interface, not the implementation.

The likely candidate is transactional proxies - are you using Spring transactions, using AspectJ or `@Transactional`?

Comment: @Marcus: That's the problem then. If you use `@Transactional` and `<tx:annotation-driven/>`, you cannot cast the bean to `MyClass`, you have to use the interface.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but to add a bit here...

You don't _have_ to use the interface, but in order to autowire the class directly, you need to modify the `<tx:annotation-driven />` configuration and add `proxy-target-class="true"` (this defaults to false). This lets you auto-wire directly to the class. Note that there can be weird side effects, e.g. I had used some reflection to find the parameterized type for a generic base class. The inheritance is changed due to the proxy class, so I had to take that into account. You can still wire by interface with `proxy-target-class="true"`.