# Spring: Cannot autowire a Bean which extends another Bean

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to write a JUnit Test for a Dao class. The dao do not need any save method as it is reading only some data.

The Test is using HSQLDB and I need to insert some test data first. As I do not want to write code only to make the test running I extend the DaoImpl class to have a save method.

Now I'd like to @Autowire the DaoTestImpl class but getting a **No qualifying bean of type […] found for dependency** error.

My setup in src/main looks like this:

```
interface Dao ...
@Repository("Dao") class DaoImpl implements Dao ...
```

And for the test in src/test I have the new class:

```
@Repository("DaoTestImpl") class DaoTestImpl extends DaoImpl
```

In the JUnit Test I'm using

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("DaoTestImpl")
private DaoTestImpl daoTestImpl;
```

Is there something wrong when autowireing a Bean which extends another Bean? If the DaoTestImpl class is implementing the interface Spring will find the proper Bean. But in this case I cannot test the DaoImpl class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the interface as a field and add qualifier using the name of the implemented class. Then it will autowire as expected.
The code will look like as bellow :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("daoTestImpl")
// The interface
private Dao dao;
```

Comment: Ok, this will work. But I don't understand the problem by using a concrete class?

Comment: It is mainly because spring create dynamic proxies for many reasons - This link may help to understand - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6511483/5654842

Comment: I dont understand this, "who" is going to be daoTestImpl?