# Adding TransactionManager in Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactionmanager

Getting error when adding Transaction-Manager. What's wrong? :/ 
Few possible answers reffer to lack of some hibernate libraries. However It seems that all of them do persist. How to overcome this? 
Also I want to add some test data to my database. In what class is it better to insert it?
Thank you.

**ERROR:**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception 
parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested
 exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
```

**Dispatcher-Servlet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.beans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.dao" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Declare a view resolver-->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


    <!-- Connects to the database based on the jdbc properties information-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class ="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name ="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name ="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/minivledb"/>
        <property name ="username" value="root"/>
        <property name ="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Declares hibernate object -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> ${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- A list of all the annotated bean files, which are mapped with database tables-->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Course </value>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Student </value>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Department </value>  
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Module </value>  
                <value> miniVLE.beans.TimeSlot </value> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean   id="hibernateTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DAO:**

```
@Repository
public class MiniVLEDAOImplementation implements MiniVLEDAO{

    // Used for communicating with the database
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void addStudentToDB(Student student) {         
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(student);        
}....
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class StudentService implements IStudentService{

    @Autowired
    MiniVLEDAOImplementation dao;    

    public StudentService() {
         System.out.println("*** StudentService instantiated");
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudent(String urn){
        Student s = dao.getStudentFromDB(urn);
        return s;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        dao.addStudentToDB(student);
    }...
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class miniVLEController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;
```

After adding the aopalliance-1.0.jar getting next
**ERROR:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'miniVLEController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: miniVLE.service.StudentService miniVLE.controller.miniVLEController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set miniVLE.service.StudentService field miniVLE.controller.miniVLEController.studentService to sun.proxy.$Proxy536
```

One of the solutions was to add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`into the dispatcher-servlet. 
next **Error:**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'miniVLEController' defined in file 
[C:\Users\1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\com3014_mini_VLE\build\web\WEB-
INF\classes\miniVLE\controller\miniVLEController.class]: BeanPostProcessor before 
instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the problem escalation:

Needed to find `aspectjrt-1.x.x.jar` that was missing to overcome last error and then to overcome org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder.PartialComparable error you need to get `aspectjtools-1.X.X.jar`

here I found all extra libraries i needed
http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException

Answer (score 1):

You need to add aopalliance.jar dependency.
If you use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What If I'm not using Maven? :)

Comment: You can download it from http://www.findjar.com/jar/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar.html and then add it to your classpath.

Comment: Do you have setter for @Autowired StudentService studentService;

Comment: Also refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570322/proxy-exception-while-injecting-spring-bean-into-jsf-bean

Comment: Just a sugestion. If you are not using maven (yet) you should take a look at it ! I use it now for even the smallest projects and it supports you on solving these kind of issues very nicely. There are some things happening sometimes resulting in WTH??, but after a while you get used to solve these issues :)