# Spring autowire multiple service Implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have one base interface and two implementations

```
public interface AnimalService
{
    public void eat();
}

@Service("animalService")
@Transactional
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService
{
    @Override
    public void eat()
    {
        System.out.println("i'm eating");
    }
}

@Service("birdService")
@Transactional
public class BirdServiceImpl extends AnimalServiceImpl
{
    public void fly()
    {
        System.out.println("i'm flying");
    }
}
```

In my main method try to call this two service implementation in this way:

```
public class test
{
    @Autowired
    private AnimalService animalService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("birdService")
    private AnimalService birdService;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        animalService.eat();
        birdService.eat();
        birdService.fly();
    }
}
```

This will give compilation error, since birdService can't find method fly(). Then I thought maybe the reason is i autowire AnimalService instead of BirdServiceImpl, So i change my autowire code from this:

```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("birdService")
   private AnimalService birdService;
```

change to :

```
   @Autowired
   private BirdServiceImpl birdService;
```

But this will give me a runtime error, which is "can't find bean BirdServiceImpl".
I have google a lot of document, some say use @Resource. But this doesn't work for me. Some say register the bean in Spring Context, while all my bean registration is done by annotation. I don't want to touch Spring Context.

Now My solution is to add a new interface

```
public interface BirdService extends AnimalService
{
    public void fly();
}
```

And let my BirdServiceImpl to implement this interface

```
    public class BirdServiceImpl extends AnimalServiceImpl extends BirdService
    {
        public void fly()
        {
            System.out.println("i'm flying");
        }
    }
```

And my main class change to this:

```
public class test
{
    @Autowired
    private AnimalService animalService;
    @Autowired
    private BirdService birdService;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        animalService.eat();
        birdService.eat();
        birdService.fly();
    }
}
```

Now is ok . But for me, this is not perfect. If I use plain java, i can just write single interface and multiple implementation. In the main method I can choose which implementation to use. Why in spring, i have to build a new interface for each new implementation in order to let my program run.

I want to know is there any better approach for my scenario?

Comment: Your code, as is, wouldn't work with plain java either. `AnimalService` doesn't have a `fly` method and regardless what you use Spring or plain java (heck spring is java) it will not find the method. Injection of the `BirdServiceImpl` will fail because, depending on your config, a proxy will be created to apply AOP. By default interfaces are used, as you are implementing an interface, so your bean will be an `AnimalService` but not one of the implementations, that will be a dynamic proxy implementing all the interfaces. Which, imho, i as it should be as you should be programming to interfaces.

Comment: you are right, if i use plain java, still can not call fly(), unless i initialize the bean like this: BirdServiceImpl birdService = new BirdServiceImpl();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you are actually exposing two issues:

**1. Inheritance issue**

This problem doesn't depends on Spring Framework, but is due by your misconception about inheritance.
If you declare your service as `AnimalService`, you obviously can use it only as an `AnimalService`, regardless its real implementation.
If you want to use concrete implementations methods, you need to cast your object.

**2. 'Autowiring a class' issue**

This should normally work in Spring, so if your code doesn't work depends on your context configuration. Maybe you are also using AOP or transactions in your app,
If so, an autoproxy generator is enabled. This could cause your problem.

Take a look at this question: [Spring Autowiring class vs. interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2387431/1061499). And note that:

> When using autoproxies, you need to program to the interface, not the implementation

**3. Just a note**

How can you use `()` at the end of a Java interface/class name?

Comment: Yes, I also use the transaction annotation for each of my service, i think i need to check my AOP. I have update my code

Comment: i think both of your guys' answers are right, here i got one more question, actually, all of my transactional annotation is set to read-only, is that mean i can't write data to my database through my service layer?

Comment: I think if i really want to suspend the transaction, i need to add propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED in the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

As I read in your question, you have already fixed the problem by creating an `Interface` for the inherited class `BirdService`. You only complain because you have to create a new Interface...

When I read your question, another question comes to mind: Which AOP are you using? Perhaps you have to add the CGLIB to your classpath (or Maven POM or Gradle).

Reading some of the Spring AOP [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types), I found this:

> **If the class of a target** object that is to be proxied (hereafter
>   simply referred to as the target class) **doesn’t implement any
>   interfaces, then a CGLIB-based proxy will be created.** This is the
>   easiest scenario, because JDK proxies are interface based, and no
>   interfaces means JDK proxying isn’t even possible.