# How to autowire a service and a repository together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, repository, autowired

I have to fix the following error. Anyone can help

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'searchController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   com.website.dev.controller.SearchController.setRecordingService(com.website.dev.service.RecordingService);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.website.dev.service.RecordingService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

    private RecordingService recordingService;

    @Autowired
    public void setRecordingService(RecordingService recordingService) {
        this.recordingService = recordingService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public String showSearch(){
        return "search";
    }
}

@Service("recordingService")
public interface RecordingService  {

    //methods
}


public class RecordingServiceImpl implements RecordingService  {

    @Autowired
    private RecordingRepository recordingRepository;

    //methods that use recordingRepository
}

public interface RecordingRepository {


}

@Repository
public class RecordingJpaRepository implements RecordingRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

   //methods that use entityManager
}
```

**service-context.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan
           base-package="com.website.dev.service">
        </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

**website-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan 
    base-package="com.website.dev.controller"> // searchcontroller is in this package
</context:component-scan>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context:component-scan 
    base-package="com.enepath.dev.controller">
</context:component-scan>
```

**EDIT**

If I autowire RecordingServiceImpl I get the following

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'recordingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.website.dev.repository.RecordingRepository
>   com.website.dev.service.RecordingServiceImpl.recordingRepository;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.website.dev.repository.RecordingRepository] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following configuration in service-context.xml and this solved my issue

```
   <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
   <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.website.dev.service">
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.website.dev.repository">
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.website.dev.repository.jpa">
    </context:component-scan>
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.website.dev.service.RecordingService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`

If we look above exception, we will find that spring container is unable to create or instantiate the bean of type `com.website.dev.service.RecordingService`.

It is because `POJO class` is not managed by `spring container`.

`@Autowire annotation` will work only those objects which are managed by spring (ie created by the spring container).

you should annotate the RecordingServiceImpl class as Service

```
@Service
public class RecordingServiceImpl implements RecordingService
```

and remove `@Service("recordingService")` from

```
public interface RecordingService  {

    //methods
}
```

`RecordingServiceImpl` would be managed by `Spring container` and spring would be able to `create the bean`.

Comment: I tried this already. According to [skaffman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2387550/2511306) you can autowire both the interface and the implementation. @Rahul please see my edit

Comment: Yes you can autowire both but i am saying make RecordingServiceImpl as @Service instead of RecordingService.

Comment: Yeah i see and you wrote `I autowire RecordingServiceImpl`.

Comment: That is what you asked. isn't it? I autowired the class not the interface

Comment: i am saying simply that do it as in answer..`@Service
public class RecordingServiceImpl implements RecordingService`

Comment: I did that and this is the error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recordingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire`... SEE EDIT