# Can't autowire Spring Security implementation class

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to make BasicAuth for my REST API and here is my problem.

**AccountConfiguration**

```java
// Spring Security uses accounts from our database
@Configuration
public class AccountConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserAuthService userAuthService;

    @Autowired
    public AccountConfiguration(UserAuthService userAuthService) {
        this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userAuthService);
    }
}
```

In constructor IntelliJ tells me

> Could not autowire. No beans of "UserAuthService type found

but I have that bean in the same package, here it is:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserAuthService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find the user: " + username);
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
    }
}
```

Here is my 3rd configuration file for Spring Security:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // allow everyone to register an account; /console is just for testing
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/console/**").permitAll();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

        // making H2 console working
        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();

        /*
        https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#when-to-use-csrf-protection
        for non-browser APIs there is no need to use csrf protection
        */
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

So how can I fix that? What's the problem here? Why it can't autowire `UserAuthService`?

Comment: Apart from intellij intellisense error. What error do you get when you try to run the code ? Sometimes, intellij gets it wrong.

Comment: I'm not getting any error but my whole authentication just doesn't work and I thought it's just because of that. I don't know if I can edit this post with more details about my authentication not workign or I should create a new one.

Comment: I fixed my other issue and this seems like just IntelliJ bug, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing code to inject the interface, rather than the implementation. It's a transactional proxy.

```
private UserDetailsService userAuthService;

@Autowired
public AccountConfiguration(UserDetailsService userAuthService) {
    this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
}
```

[Spring Autowiring class vs. interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387431/spring-autowiring-class-vs-interface)

Comment: Still doesn't work, now just says "Could not autowire. No beans of "UserAuthService type found"

Comment: It's `UserDetailsService` not `UserAuthService`. Make sure you made the right change (2 changes). Also, post the error stacktrace for a better understanding.